# Systemd unit not found after OS crash and hard reboot

Tags: systemd

I'm running Linux Mint kernel version 4.15.0-42-generic, and have a user systemd service file at `~/.local/share/systemd/user/my.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=30s

[Service]
ExecStart="/my/command"
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
PrivateTmp=true
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It was installed by placing that file, then running `systemctl --user daemon-reload` and then `systemctl --user enable my.service`.

It works great, except when the OS crashes and a hard reboot (power cycle) is initiated. Upon logging back in, the service is not running.

In fact, it is not even found.

First commands after rebooting prove that systemd has lost the service, even though the file still exists and hasn't changed:

```
matt@brego:~$ systemctl --user status my.service
Unit my.service could not be found.

matt@brego:~$ ls -la ~/.local/share/systemd/user
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 matt matt 4096 Oct 16 15:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 matt matt 4096 Sep 28 13:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt  458 Oct 16 15:56 my.service

matt@brego:~$ loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT             TTY             
        c2       1000 matt             seat0                            

1 sessions listed.
```

Running `systemctl --user start my.service` or `systemctl --user enable my.service` results in the same error: `Unit my.service could not be found.`

I have to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` and then I can enable the service. Every. Time. After. Hard. Reboots.

How can I force systemd to run the service after the user logs in after the system reboots and after a power cycle? And to not forget about the service?

**Edits to address further questions**

Outputs of various commands after a hard reboot running as the same user:

```
matt@brego:~$ cat /etc/pam.d/systemd-user 
# This file is part of systemd.
#
# Used by systemd --user instances.

@include common-account

session  required pam_selinux.so close
session  required pam_selinux.so nottys open
session  required pam_loginuid.so
session  required pam_limits.so
@include common-session-noninteractive
session optional pam_systemd.so

matt@brego:~$ ps -U ${UID} -f | grep systemd
matt      1341     1  0 13:34 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
matt      1384  1341  0 13:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
matt      6870  1913  0 14:12 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto systemd

matt@brego:~$ systemctl --user list-units --type=target
UNIT           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                                                        
basic.target   loaded active active Basic System                                                                       
default.target loaded active active Default                                                                            
paths.target   loaded active active Paths                                                                              
sockets.target loaded active active Sockets                                                                            
timers.target  loaded active active Timers                                                                             

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

5 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

matt@brego:~$ systemctl --user status default.target
● default.target - Default
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Tue 2018-12-04 13:34:34 MST; 38min ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Dec 04 13:34:34 brego systemd[1341]: Reached target Default.
```

Comment: - Does a file, which loads [`pam_systemd.so`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) exist in `/etc/pam.d/` - most likely named `systemd-user`?
- After a crash, and before executing any other command, what does `ps -U ${UID} -f | grep systemd` return (executed as the regular user under which you're seeing those issues)?
- What does `systemctl --user list-units --type=target` return?
- What does `systemctl --user status default.target` return?
- Can you reproduce this issue using another Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 or Fedora 29)?